# Do I have enough time to connect (changing terminals and rechecking bags) at LAS?

Tags: transit, short-connections, las

I have a Southwest Airlines domestic flight landing in Las Vegas at 4:40 pm in Terminal 1. I have an international flight on Norwegian Air. leaving from Terminal 3 at 6 pm. Will I have enough time to pick up my bag and make my second flight?

Comment: This seems rather high risk to me, given that, if you're late, you've arranged your own connection and the airline isn't responsible.

Comment: If there is not even the slightest problem, maybe.  Unless the Southwest flight arrives early and you are seated up front, don't expect to be at the Norwegian check in desk before 5pm.  Check in and back drop will close at 5:15pm.

Comment: That cuts it very close even if SWA is on time. I'd take an earlier flight.

Comment: I would be amazed at making this connection.  Furthermore, since you have two tickets Norwegian doesn't owe you anything **when** you miss your flight.

Comment: Thank all who responded. I changed my first flight to the morning one. As much as I hate long layovers there looks to be plenty to do at the Las Vegas airport, and I will buy a day pass for the lounge, so it will be bearable. I checked with Norwegian air after I read your answers, they do not accept checked bags after 5:15 for that flight. Terry in WA

Answer (score 6):

This is not enough time, certainly not with checked luggage. Check-in, including bag drop [closes 1 hour before departure](http://www.norwegian.com/us/travel-info/check-in-and-boarding/check-in-deadlines/). That's 5pm, 20 minutes after your flight is scheduled to arrive, and you must collect your bags and [change terminals](https://www.mccarran.com/Go/Inter-TerminalShuttle.aspx), which, as I understand it, requires a bus that comes every 12-15 minutes. You also have to get yourself out of Terminal 1, which is a large complex of several buildings, and wait for your baggage to arrive, which has been known to take a while

If you arrive 10 minutes early, your bags arrive quickly and are the first ones off the baggage carousel, the curb where the bus pulls up is right in front of you, the bus leaves the moment you get there, and the Norwegian check-in desk is right in front of the door, and you run like heck, it's not, you know, utterly impossible. If any one of those things doesn't happen, it's not enough time. If your Southwest flight is 10 minutes late and it takes 10 minutes for the bags and you to make it to baggage claim, you're already too late before you've even left Terminal 1.

And since you've arranged your own connection by booking two separate tickets, the airline isn't responsible if you miss your flight, and you could well be spending one or more nights in Vegas. I'd book a much earlier flight.

Comment: @pnuts As I read that, it's 1 hour because the flight leaves from the US, but I suppose it isn't perfectly clear. However, I'd say that this is so little time that adding 15 minutes still isn't going to make it ok.

Comment: Add to this that the baggage delivery in LAS leaves something to be desired.  I usually have to wait a bit for my bags after getting to the right carousel.